# How to exclude useless sections when generating cores on Linux?

Tags: linux

I have access to two Linux distributions, both customized Debian.

Using an identical test program, on one a generated core file is ~35 MiB. On the other, it is ~290 MiB. The program spawns some threads, makes some allocations, then busy-loops forever.

Inspecting the core with `readelf`, I see that the bigger one includes sections like this:

```
  LOAD           0x000000000815e6b8 0x00007f8594021000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000003fdf000 0x0000000003fdf000  R      0x1
```

Which, looking at the memory maps, corresponds to:

```
7f8594021000-7f8598000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
Size:              65404 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
Pss:                   0 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:            0 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: mr mw me nr
```

I understand this region to be unused memory dedicated to thread arenas. **The region exists in both distributions at run-time but is only written to the core file on one of them. Why would this be so?**

The `coredump_filter` is identical on both (0x33), so it's not that.

**Edit:** I've further tracked it down to a difference in the way that running `gcore` on a process changes the virtual memory regions in the kernel. On the one with smaller cores, it does not mark them as 'written to' but on the larger, it does. Specifically, it creates a `anon_vma` structure.

Comment: What's different about the two distributions?

Comment: A lot; the packages, the kernel, the configs... they don't share a lineage. It's hard to say why this particular thing could be different.

Comment: If the kernels are different, it could very well be that one of them is modified in some way to dump cores differently.  It's really impossible to know without having enough information to reproduce the problem independently.